# How to edit the Hashmap list values based on the Key

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to edit the list values based on the key . 
My code is:

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> map= new HashMap<String,List<String>>()

List<String> listOMSColorCode = new ArrayList<String>()
List<String> listOMSColorCodeDisplayOrder = new ArrayList<String>()

listOMSColorCode.add("orange")  
listOMSColorCode.add("apple")
listOMSColorCode.add("banana")

map.put("Key1",listOMSColorCode)
```

after some logic happen here , Now I want to replace/edit apple with grapes in the same index of map list.

Comment: You can remove `apple` and add `grapes`.

Comment: On a List, you can use `indexOf` and `set` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `ListIterator` for that:

```
for(ListIterator<String> li = listOMSColorCode.listIterator(); li.hasNext(); ) {
    if(li.next().equals("apple")) {
        li.set("grape");
    }
}
```

`if(li.next().equals("apple")) {` checks if the current element of the `listIterator` is an `"apple"` and if it is. It replaces that element with `"grape"` via the the `ListIterator.set()` method

Comment: I'm curious... Would this be possible using the stream API? I mean replacing all occurrences of a `String` `x` with `y` in the value of a given key...

Comment: what about  listOMSColorCode.replaceAll(a -> {
      if (a.equals("apple")) return "grape";
      else return a;
    });  ??

Comment: @StephanHogenboom Will work but then you have a lot of replacement operations for nothing though

Comment: @deHaar you could stream the list, and then if the element is an apple, return a grape, else just return the element. But this would then have to be collected into a new list, which would be somewhat inefficient

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient, because it iterates the list for every occurence, but this will replace all occurences:

```
List<String> modifiedList = map.get("Key1");
int index = 0;
while((index = modifiedList.indexOf("apple")) != -1){
    modifiedList.set(index, "grapes");
}
```

Or using a utility method from Collections class:

```
List<String> modifiedList = map.get("Key1");
Collections.replaceAll(modifiedList, "apple", "grapes");
```

Comment: `Collections.replaceAll` seems like a real nice utility, and will choose the best variant depending on the `list` size and if it is random access. +1